# Strange multiplication error

Tags: java, computer-science

Why would something simple like this:

```
System.out.println("test problem: " + 194*194*194*409);
```

output something like this:

```
test problem: -1308701240
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html - look at min and max of int and "32-bit signed two's complement integer"

Comment: you had overflowed the integer size

Comment: Hint. What website is this? reflect on the name, deeply

Comment: @Adel I had not noticed the **overflow** in the name is in bold until now.

Answer (score 11):

Because you've overflowed an integer.  See the limits on the numbers handled by integers in the java documentation.

Comment: If you are using numeric constants in Java without any prefix or suffix, the values are interpreted as `int` and the result will be an integer too. Your result is equal to 2,986,266,056 which is above the maximum value that can be contained by an 32 bit integer (being 2,147,483,647 or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Answer (score 8):

Rather than give you the direct answer, I'll suggest some steps.

- Work out the *type* of arithmetic you're doing (what type is the literal 194? what type is the result of the multiplication operator you're using?)
- What do you expect the answer to be?
- Can your result type handle that answer?
- What does Java do for results it can't handle?

For bonus points, refer to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) for the last part...

Answer (score 2):

From [15.17.1. Multiplication Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17)

> If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the 
>   mathematical product as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. As a result, if overflow occurs, then the sign of the result may not be the same as the sign of the mathematical product of the two operand values.

We have `194*194*194*409=2986266056`

In binary the result is `1011 0001 1111 1110 1100 1101 1100 1000`

The last 32 bits are `1011 0001 1111 1110 1100 1101 1100 1000`, so we did not lose any bits by the overflow, but the sign has changed.

Since `int` is represented in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)), the results is 
`2^32 - 2986266056 = -1308701240`.

Everything works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an overflow on the result of the operation. 2.986.266.056 not a valid int value.

Answer (score -7):

Try to make first the mathematical OP and then convert the result to string.